# Using vue-ellipse-progress component, is there any way where I can have two different colors for same circle indicating high and low value?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I want to indicate the high/low in the circle where I can display the different color if the progress value exceeds 60. Eg, if my value is 80 then till 60 it should show green color and remaining 20 should be in red color. Is it possible to achieve this using vue-ellipse-progress?

```
          <vue-ellipse-progress
            :progress="myvariable"
            :angle="-90"
            color="#1565C0"
            emptyColor="#BBDEFB"
            :size="180"
            :thickness="10"
            emptyThickness="15%"
            fontColor="black"
            dot="10 white"
          >
            <span>{{myvariable}} </span>
          </vue-ellipse-progress>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got one solution to this. By adding gradient to the color attribute helps to show the colors accordingly.

:color = "gradient"

gradient: {
radial: false,
colors: [
{
color: '#1565C0',
offset: 80,
opacity: '1',
},
{
color: 'red',
offset: 40,
opacity: '1',
},
]
}